# Setting an dropped event ID

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Using `fullcalendar 5.0`, I am trying to add a unique ID to a dropped external event and I can't get it to work. It seems like I should be using `event.setProp` and I can see that is modifying `event._def` but it doesn't seem to be reflected in the public properties.

I have these event handlers in the new Calendar object:

```js
...,
eventReceive: function(info){
    console.log('In eventReceive')
    console.log('id = ' + info.event.id + '; _def.id = ' + info.event._def.id)
    info.event.setProp('id', 'myshinyid')
    console.log('Back in eventReceive')
    console.log('id = ' + info.event.id + '; _def.id = ' + info.event._def.id)
},
eventAdd: function(info){
},
eventChange: function(info){
    console.log('In eventChange')
    console.log('id = ' + info.event.id + '; _def.id = ' + info.event._def.id)
},
```

Working example [here](https://codepen.io/davidorme/pen/WNrYwRw?editors=0011)

That creates the sequence I would expect: `eventReceive` triggers, `setProp` fires off `eventChange` and then returns to `eventReceive`. I can see the `_def` being altered, but it isn't exposed.

```
In eventReceive
1:106 id = ; _def.id = undefined
1:114 In eventChange
1:115 id = ; _def.id = myshinyid
1:108 Back in eventReceive
1:109 id = ; _def.id = myshinyid
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response but I just checked for the same issue and I find a solution.

In your Draggable element you need to add the eventData options and you can set your id there =>

```
new FullCalendar.Draggable(containerEl, {
    itemSelector: '.fc-event', // Change with the identifier of your external events
    eventData: function(eventEl) {
        const event = JSON.parse(eventEl.getAttribute('data-event')); // I have all my event info in a stringify json object on each elements
        event.id = generateUUID(); // Here you can add your id
        return event; // Your id will be saved
    }
});
```